# Parsing CSV data into structure

Tags: c, csv

I have to put the data from a csv file (name, address, telephone...) to a structure of my C program. It's been unsuccessful, unfortunately. I tried using strtok function to break into tokens every time it finds a ";" (because we're dealing with a Comma Separated File).

Here's what I've done:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX_STR_LEN 256
#define MAX_BOOKS 256


struct estrutura
{
    int id;
    char nome[40];
    char endereco[40];
    char cidade[40];
    char pais[20];
    char cep[10];
    char nasc[12];
    char telefone[14];
    char total[20];
};

struct estrutura cliente[200];

FILE *pFile;

//allocate buffer in each line

char *buf = malloc(MAX_STR_LEN);
char *tmp; 

 void abrir();
/*  Functions to be coded
int menu();
int menu2(); //manutencao de clientes
void adicionar();
void alterar();
void excluir();
void exibir();
void pesquisar(); */

main()
{
    system("cls");
    abrir();
    //menu();
}

void abrir() //open the csv file and copy it to 
{
    /* FileStream for the Library File */
    FILE *pFile;

    /* allocation of the buffer for every line in the File */
    char *buf = malloc(MAX_STR_LEN);
    char *tmp; 

    /* if the space could not be allocated, return an error */
    if (buf == NULL) {
        printf ("No memory\n");
            }

    if ( ( pFile = fopen( "control.csv", "r" ) ) == NULL ) //Reading a file
    {
        printf( "File could not be opened.\n" );
    }

    int i = 0;
    while (fgets(buf, 255, pFile) != NULL)
    {
        if ((strlen(buf)>0) && (buf[strlen (buf) - 1] == '\n')) //checa leitura
            buf[strlen (buf) - 1] = '\0';       

        tmp = strtok(buf, ";"); 
        cliente[i].id = atoi(tmp); //atoi for int

        tmp = strtok(NULL, ";"); //use strcpy for char
        strcpy(cliente[i].nome,tmp);

        tmp = strtok(NULL, ";");
        strcpy(cliente[i].endereco, tmp);

        tmp = strtok(NULL, ";");
        strcpy(cliente[i].cidade, tmp);

        tmp = strtok(NULL, ";");
        strcpy(cliente[i].pais, tmp);

        tmp = strtok(NULL, ";");
        strcpy(cliente[i].cep, tmp);

        tmp = strtok(NULL, ";");
        strcpy(cliente[i].nasc, tmp);

        tmp = strtok(NULL, ";");
        strcpy(cliente[i].telefone, tmp);

        tmp = strtok(NULL, ";");
        strcpy(cliente[i].total, tmp);

        //tempBook.ID = atoi(buf); fix below
        printf("%i, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s \n",i, cliente[i].id , cliente[i].nome, cliente[i].endereco, cliente[i].cidade, cliente[i].pais, cliente[i].cep, cliente[i].nasc, cliente[i].telefone, cliente[i].total);

        i++;
    }
    //free(buf);
    fclose(pFile);
}
```

How can I solve this problem? I can't successfully copy the data from 100 clients in the csv to a structure.

Thank you since now!

Comment: Please post the first few lines of your csv file.

Comment: Please also add a description of what problem you're seeing - your question so far tells us your aim and the code, but does not indicate what your problem might be!

Comment: In the code you posted, you never call `abrir` but you call `menu` that does not exist.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon, but more urgently, please read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).  An MCVE includes some sample input data, the actual and expected output, and minimal code that produces the output shown.  You don't say what goes wrong, but you never check that `strtok()` is returning a non-null pointer.

Comment: With `fgets()`, you can specify the full size of the buffer.  You should not bother with `malloc()`; `char buffer[MAX_STR_LEN];` would be sensible, and specify either `MAX_STR_LEN` or `sizeof(buffer)` as the length argument to `fgets()`.  Suddenly writing 255 after allocating `MAX_STR_LEN` bytes is a recipe for disaster (and the reduction by one is unnecessary); don't do that.

Answer (score 1):

There are three main problems here:

1. The format string in `printf("%i, %s, %s, %s, ...)` doesn't match the parameters, you need one more `%i`: `printf("%i, %i, %s, %s, %s, ...)`.
2. In your code you never call `abrir()` but you call `menu()`, which doesn't exist, therefore your code doesn't even compile.
3. If you are on Windows (and only then) you need `fopen(..., "rt"))` instead
    of `fopen(..., "r"))`

Furthermore (not causing actual problems in your code):

`char *buf = malloc(MAX_STR_LEN);` can be replaced by `char buf[MAX_STR_LEN];`. It's pointless to allocate memory dynamically if the amount of memory is known at compile time. In that case you must of course not call `free(buf)` (which is commented out anyway).

Following declarations just after `struct estrutura cliente[200];` are useless, you can remove them.

```
FILE *pFile;

//allocate buffer in each line

char *buf = (char*)malloc(MAX_STR_LEN);
char *tmp;
```

Otherwise the program should work fine unless your input file has fields that are larger than the field in your `struct estrutura`.